# Not using user's current location but apple requests "The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key"

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am using Google Maps in my app, and I tried to deploy the app to iTunes Connect but I received an email stating

> "ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in `Info.plist` - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain an `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that.."

My problem is, that I do NOT request the user's current location in the app but yet I still got this email. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: add description for this key in your Info.plist NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription. You don't request but googlemaps framework can do this

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik what should I write as the string explaining why I need the location?

Comment: smth like "Application need access to your location, to obtain your location data"))